# Customize Navbar Collapse button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i change the color of the collapse button there? and the white lines like the divider. here is the picture. Can someone help me? im new to css,bootstrap and html so please help me. or give me some ideas.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
<nav class ="navbar navbar-default" role= "navigation">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class ="navbar-header">
            <button type ="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Students</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>

            </ul>

         </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
```

Here is my css.

```
       #fot{ position:fixed;
       bottom:0;

       }
      .navbar-default{
        background-color:rgb(193,57,45);

       }
      .navbar .nav > li > a{
       color:#ffe6e6;
       }
      .navbar .nav > li > a:hover{
        color:#000000;
        }
     .navbar .nav .active > a{
      background-color:rgb(193,57,45);
     color:#000000;
      }
    .navbar .nav .active > a:hover{
    background:none;
    color:#fff;
    }
  .nav .nav-divider{
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #a92419;
  border-left: 1px solid #c1392d;
  }
  @media(max-width: 768px) 
 {.nav .nav-divider{
  height: 1px;
 margin: 0 10px;
 background-color:#a92419;

  }
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
background-color: #fff;
margin:0 0 4px;
width: 25px;
height: 5px;

 }
```

Comment: Use the CSS properties background and border-color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
.icon-bar
{
  background:green !important; /*Whatever colour you want for icon lines*/
}
.navbar-toggle
{
  background:yellow !important; /*Whatever colour you want for background */
}
```

> In the CSS `!important` forces to apply property aside it over actual properties of Bootstrap CSS.

**Update:** In your CSS **ADD Following code**:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: darkblue; /* Whatever Colour you want */
}
```

Comment: what is the use of !important sir?

Comment: Sir how 'bout the white lines before the students? how can i change the color of that?

Comment: I think it's not a divider sir.

Comment: Click on mobile device icon there for viewing as smaller device demo.

Comment: @TikboyPengan Ok i got it wrong what you want  now check the update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse...just define some css on button class like this

**CSS**

```
button.navbar-toggle{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    color:#000;
    // and so on according to what style u want...
}

button.navbar-toggle span{
   background:#000;/*change accordingly*/
   // these span are for white line you can edit the lines in this css
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir it worked on the button. But how about the white lines below? sir?

Comment: you need to check which css is already applied on `<span class="icon-bar" ></span>` and then re-write the css according to that